# Don't Scroll Body With Mousewheel on a fixed, scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a webpage with a fixed y scrollable sidenav and a main body. When I scroll with my mouse scrollwheel, pointer inside the side nav, sometimes the body will scroll depending on where the element is positioned. Technically the margin of the main body is still overlapping with the side nav due to bootstrap offset like `offset-md-3`.

[image: Example]
[image: Margin]

How can I stop the main body from scrolling while the mouse is on the sidenav? I need the solution without using any plugins. jQuery and Bootstrap 4 only please.

My initial instinct was like this, but changing to fixed caused the main body to snap back to the top.

I disabled scrolling on hover over the `.SideNav`, but I needed to keep the scrollbar for continuity.

```
$(".SideNav").hover(function () {
        $('body').css({
            "position": 'fixed',
            "overflow-y": 'scroll'
        });
    },
    function () {
        $('body').css({
            position: 'inherit',
            "overflow-y": 'scroll'

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially using fixed was causing the body to snap back to scrolling from the top of the page. I had to compensate like so.

```
    var offset;
    $(".SideNav").hover(function () {
        offset = window.pageYOffset  // Get offset to set position when fixed
        $("main").css("position", "fixed");
        $('body').css({
            "position": 'fixed',
            "overflow-y": 'scroll',
            "top": 0 - offset
        });
    },
        function () {
        $("main").css("position", "inherit");
        $('body').css({
            "position": 'inherit',
            "overflow-y": 'scroll'
        });
        $(window).scrollTop(offset);  // When scroll bar returns, set page to original position
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it to be an interesting situation and reading your answer I was wondering why you needed to also change the `position` and `top` properties although it very well may be necessary to accommodate to your specific html and css structure.

Any way, I thought I could include a different approach in a simpler/minimal scenario. Let me know what you think:

```js
var currentOverflow;
$(".SideNav").hover(()=> {
    currentOverflow = $('body').css('overflow');
 $('body').css({
     overflow: 'hidden'
    })
},
() => {
    $('body').css({
     overflow: currentOverflow
 })
});
```

```css
.SideNav{
position: fixed;
height: 100vh;
width: 20vw;
background: red;
top: 0;
left: 0
}
span{
margin-left: 30vw
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SideNav" id="fixed"></div>
        <br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span>
  <br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span>
  <br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span>
  <br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span><br><span>a</span>
```

Comment: That's a great scenario and example. One requirement that I had to fulfill was keeping the scrollbar. therefore I was having to used `position:fixed` with `overflow-y: scroll`. I think saving the css elements via in a variable is the way I will do it in the future. I had not thought of that.